# Parallel run in Chrome

Tags: node.js, protractor, cucumberjs

I am trying to implement parallel test execution in Chrome to reduce the test execution time. The framework being used is protractor-cucumber framework with Node JS. The webdriver instances open up in two tabs rather than two separate windows of Chrome.

Used the `multicapabilities` in the config file to set `testsharding` as `true` and `maxinstances` as `2`:

```
   multiCapabilities: [
        {
            shardTestFiles: true,
            maxInstances: 4,
            browserName: chrome,
            specs: ['*.spec.js']
        },
```

Chrome is opening 2 tabs instead of windows and the tests are not getting distributed across the tabs.

Comment: can you please attached your full config

Answer (score 0):

### Full config as requested

const path = require("path");

const jsonReports = process.cwd() + "/reports/json";

exports.config = {

seleniumAddress: "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub",

baseUrl: "https://www.google.co.uk",

multiCapabilities: [

```
{

  browserName: "chrome",

  shardTestFiles: true,

  maxInstances: 2


}
```

],

framework: "custom",

frameworkPath: require.resolve("protractor-cucumber-framework"),

specs: ["../features/*.feature"],

onPrepare: function() {

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

browser.manage().window().maximize();


Reporter.createDirectory(jsonReports);
```

},

cucumberOpts: {

```
strict: true,

format: 'json:./reports/json/cucumber_report.json',

require: ["../stepDefinitions/*.js"],

tags: "(@AllureScenario or @CucumberScenario or @ProtractorScenario) and (not @DatabaseTest)" //
```

},

onComplete: function () {

}

};